# Running a script in nested directories without repercussions in the executing directory

Tags: linux, shell

Like the title says I'm hoping to run a script within a nested directory structure without repercussions in the executing directory (outputs go in the sub-folder within the structure where the file it's operating on resides).

for example:

```
home/   (where we use the script)
home/data1/file1.txt
home/data2/file2.txt
home/data3/file3.txt
```

When I make a script my output goes to:

```
home/
```

but i would like the output to go like so:

```
home/data1/output1
home/data2/output2
home/data3/output3
```

**What is the best way to accomplish this? I'd appreciate any input.**

My scripts below, in case you prefer a specific case rather than general case.

Script executing the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# iterate over a NUL-delimited stream of directory names
while IFS='' read -r -d '' dirname; do
  # ...then list files in each directory:
  for file in "$dirname"/*; do
    # ignore directory contents that are not files
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    # run analysis tool
    if [[ $file == *.dmp ]]; then
      echo $dirname;
      ./gdp $file;
      #ls $dirname;
      echo "complete";
      continue
    fi
  done
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Script to be executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1;
awk '
    /Internet Protocol Version 4, Src:/{ip=$(NF-4)}
    /    Time to live/{ttl++}
    /    Time to live/{sttl=$NF}
    /    User-Agent/{}
    /    User-Agent/ && NF>6 {os=$(NF-6)" "$(NF-5)}
    /    User-Agent/ && NF<6 {os="\t"}
    /    User-Agent/{brow=$NF}
    /    User-Agent/{agent++}
    /    User-Agent/{stringtemp=sttl"\t"ip"\t"os"\t"brow}
    /    User-Agent/{string=(string)"\n"(stringtemp)}
    /Windows;/{windows++}
    /Linux;/{linux++}
    /Solaris;/{solaris++}
    /Epoch Time: /{count++}
    END{
        sub(/\\r.*$/, "", brow);
        print os;
        print "("count")" > "temp";
        print "TTL\tIP\t\tOS\t\tBROWSER";
        print string;
        print "\nSUMMARY\n\tttl\t=\t"ttl"\n\twindow\t=\t"windows"\n\tlinux\t=\t"linux"\n\tsolaris\t=\t"solaris >> "temp";
    }
' $1 > summary_$1;
sort -k2n summary_$1 | uniq > holder;
cat temp > useragents_$1;
cat holder >>  useragents_$1;
more useragents_$1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first script change:

```
./gdp $file;

to

./gdp $file $dirname;
```

in your second script change:

```
' $1 > summary_$1;
sort -k2n summary_$1 | uniq > holder;
cat temp > useragents_$1;
cat holder >>  useragents_$1;
more useragents_$1;

to

' $1 > $2/summary_$1;
sort -k2n $2/summary_$1 | uniq > $2/holder;
cat temp > $2/useragents_$1;
cat $2/holder >>  $2/useragents_$1;
more $2/useragents_$1;
```